# Python mechanize download file with original filename

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

Working on a python script to scraping multi files from a website.

The download form html is something like this:

```
<span>
    <a class="tooltip" href="download.php?action=download&amp;id=xxx&amp;authkey=yyy&amp;pass=zzz" title="Download">DL</a>
</span>
```

What I'm thinking of is:

```
f1 = open('scraping.log', 'a')
page = br.open(url)
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.select('a[href^="download.php?action=download"]'):
        link = a.attrs.get('href')
        print >>f1, link
        br.retrieve(url+link, destination)
```

However, for the retrieve I have to state out the output filename. I want to get the original filename instead of setting it as a random name. Is there any way to do that?
Moreover, as I want to add this script to run frequently in crontab, is there a way for me to set us check the scraping.log and skip those that have been downloaded before?

Comment: Which site are you scraping? You could get the filename from that.

Comment: Sorry it's a private site. For the filename, is there anyway to get filename from just the download link like above?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like "download.php", check for a [Content-Disposition header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1), e.g.:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

And ensure the filename [complies with your intent](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt):

> It is important that the receiving MUA not blindly use the
>   suggested filename.  The suggested filename SHOULD be checked (and
>   possibly changed) to see that it conforms to local filesystem
>   conventions, does not overwrite an existing file, and does not
>   present a security problem (see Security Considerations below).

Python 2:

```
import re
import mechanize  # pip install mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
r = br.open('http://yoursite.com')
#print r.info()['Content-Disposition']
unsafe_filename = r.info().getparam('filename')  # Could be "/etc/evil".
filename = re.findall("([a-zA-Z0-9 _,()'-]+[.][a-z0-9]+)$", unsafe_filename)[0]  # "-]" to match "-".
```

As for skipping links you've processed before,

```
f1 = open('scraping.log', 'a')
processed_links = f1.readlines()
page = br.open(url)
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.select('a[href^="download.php?action=download"]'):
    link = a.attrs.get('href')
    if not link in processed_links:
        print >>f1, link
        processed_links += [link]
        br.retrieve(url+link, destination)
```